# Keras Model gives different results on val set immediately after training

Tags: keras

I'm getting different results from my model using the .predict method on the validation set immediately after training than I do during the last epoch of training. Here's what I've tried:

1. Build model.
2. Train and get MSE on validation loss for the last epoch of training.
3. Run model.predict on the validation set and manually calculate the MSE.

The manually calculated MSE is always worse than the one given during training. I've also tried saving the best model and loading it before calculating the MSE again, and I see the same behavior. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
Here's the code!

```
training_data = data[:10000]
training_norm_factor = np.std(training_data)
training_mean = np.mean(training_data)
training_inputs = training_data[:,:-1].reshape((-1, look_back, 1))
training_inputs = (training_inputs - training_mean)/training_norm_factor
training_labels = (training_data[:,-1] - training_mean)/training_norm_factor

val_data = data[10000:]
val_inputs = val_data[:, :-1].reshape((-1, look_back, 1))
val_inputs = (val_inputs - training_mean)/training_norm_factor
val_labels = (val_data[:,-1] - training_mean)/training_norm_factor

# Build Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(256, input_shape=(5, 1), return_sequences=True, 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(layers.GRU(256, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))


# Compile and Train
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=1e-3, clipnorm=1.),
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              )

callbacks_list = [
    K.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=0), K.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('/Users/rickblickstead/Documents/GitHub/Volatility-
                Forecasting/MyModel.5df5', 
                monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, 
                mode='min', period=1)
]

history = model.fit(training_inputs[:, -5:], training_labels,
                    epochs=8,
                    batch_size=256,
                    shuffle=True,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list,
                    validation_data = (val_inputs[:, -5:], val_labels)
                   )

# Re-Test validation set

best_model = load_model('MyModel.5df5')
best_predictions = best_model.predict(val_inputs[:, -5:], batch_size=256, verbose=0)
print np.mean((best_predictions-val_labels)**2)
```

Comment: Can you provide code? There's no way to understand what happened from your description.

Comment: Thanks so much for applying! I added the code to the post!